# How can I get WordPress to recognize my newly created page template?

Tags: wordpress, templates, wordpress-theming

I recently created a new template page, I put the obligatory

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: New Page Template for testing
*/
?>
```

as the first part of the code.

Then I uploaded it to the /www/wp-content/themes/neoclassical (where all of the other custom page templates are located).

I now try to change the Template of any page to the new theme, and the new page template does not show!

Any ideas on what I need to do to get this to show up as an option on the "Add Page" area?

I have tried changing the theme to another one and back to the original theme, all to no avail.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: What is the filename for your template? Did you tried it without spaces?

Comment: The filename is WestSideOutLetB_1side.php - no spaces involved.

Comment: I mean Template name without spaces. Try a shorten name, without numbers, "_" and anything else.. When I create and upload a template, it automatically shows up in WP-admin

Comment: I just tried that, still with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out that the original developer had put the backup copy of the site in the "LiveFiles" directory, and had pointed the site to "Stuff".  I was just uploading to the wrong area.

Answer (score 2):

For future visitors:

I just had this problem in WordPress 4.8. Turns out I had removed the `index.php` file from my theme, which was causing the theme not to show the template dropdown.

To fix this just create an empty `index.php` file in your theme folder.

(WordPress does try to warn you this file is missing on the **Themes** page in the admin panel — but you might not visit that page while trying to fix this bug.)

**Update:** Trace has mentioned in the comment below that a missing `style.css` can also cause this to happen.

Comment: I had this issue as well, but it was style.css I accidently removed (because my real stylesheet is in a different location). WP looks for certain files, like style.css, index.php etc. to validate a theme, and if it doesn't see them, while the theme can still be "active", it's not seen as a complete theme by WP and hence, it doesn't function as expected.

Answer (score 1):

if the code of the custom template is not good. it wont show.

try using one of the examples here.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates

Comment: Yes, that's worth a go. Or in fact, @Steve, try _just_ putting that comment block you've posted in a file. It should certainly appear in the page template list even if there's no code in it.

Answer (score 1):

you just write this sentence and go to admin panal and add new page than you see Template box and find your template page name.

Answer (score 0):

In case this suddenly happens in a working theme, try to delete delete the row starting with _transient_files from wp_options table. That solved the issue for me.